# Split a web application into services/modules to scalability

Tags: node.js, scalability

I have some doubts about how to develop a large scale web application.
After some research I thought of some idea:

1: Develop the frontend in a language that can handle a large number of simultaneous requests. Understanding frontend as the module/service
which will be responsible to deliver the pages to the client.

2: Use Nodejs as frontend language (golang is not an option here).

3: A request to a backend module will be made by AJAX, and the server must redirect to the appropriate module.

4: The backend is separated into modules/services using the technology (programming language) better for each one to use.

5: Each module will have its own server or set of servers.

My questions are:

1: This is the best way to develop a large and scalable system?

2: How it would be to the organization server level, in order to redirect every request to your service. Because each service to work
the most efficient way?

Well, trying to clarify my ideas here...
I see now how wrong I've write my question...

The application is one that deal with image manipulation, and a heavy database.
What I am planning to do is split the whole system in a frontend that will just serve the web pages, and backend applications, which will deal with all the heavy work.
Each of these application, service/module..., would expose an API and the frontend will use these APIs, throught AJAX to handle the actions requested by the users.

With organization at server level I meant something like how would I make the server redirect requests for pages to nodejs and requests for data to the appropriate module.

In short, I think that I could say, how does the serve know that the request is for an API or for a page..

I guess what I'm looking for is RPC, but I don't really uderstand what that means, nor how it works.

Comment: If I understand correctly you should not redirect incoming requests but make a necessary API calls from your front-end node project to your back-end services.

Comment: lets say I make an api call from my node script. I'd make that call using a url or call it like I'd call a program installed in my server? My host the backend in the same server as the frontend, and call it using AJAX. that would involve a url right? how would the server, based on the url, redirect to the right service?

Answer (score 1):

> 1: This is the best way to develop a large and scalable system?

Developing a large and scalable system doesn't nessesarily have a single answer. There are a multitude of architectures out there that works in it's own way, solving different problems.

So depending on your actual requirements, the answer is yes and no. If you want some more helpful tips, you should give us a little more information about what you want to scale, not just how.

> 2: How it would be to the organization server level, in order to redirect every request to your service. Because each service to work the most efficient way?

I'm not sure what you mean here exactly, but I believe you are refering to either if/how you would go about distributing work to the different services/servers in your architecture?

Usually, if you have 1 or more servers/applications providing the same service, you would use a load-balancer to distribute the work. If you are thinking about how to send the correct work to the correct service (For example sending some image to a image processing service, and a database query to a database) then you would do all of this logic in a server that would handle the reuqests. Traditionally that would be done by the webserver, by calling the required services to perform a request.

If you need some more specialized help, please provide more info about your application.

Comment: I've updated my question. sorry if I just made things worst to understand.

Comment: I want to build a web application and I want to separate the frontend from backend in the development process. I can do that by serving static HTML pages and updating the dynamic content inside the HTML with AJAX requests to a REST service. In this approach, the browser is effectively making more than two HTTP requests for rendering a page. Is it the right way to do it? or is there a better approach?